# $\beta$ reduction equational equality

Tags: category-theory

In [Categories, Types and Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262011255), authors talk about exponential objects in section 2.3.1.

> Let $C$ be a Cartesian category, and $a,b \in Ob_C$. The exponent of $a$ and $b$ is an object $b^a$ together with a morphism $eval_{alb}: b^a \times a\rightarrow b$ (evaluation map), and for every object $c$ an operation $\Lambda_c : C[c\times a,b]\rightarrow C[c, b^a]$ such that for all morphisms $f: c\times a\rightarrow b$, $h:c\rightarrow b^a$, the following equation holds:
>   $\beta. eval_{a,b} \circ (\Lambda (f)\times id_a )=f$
>   $\eta. \Lambda_c(eval_{a,b}\circ(h\times id_a))=h$

Can you please show me the steps to derive the last two equations?

Comment: This is a (possible) *definition* of an exponential object; what do you want to prove exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The following morphism and commuting morphisms explain why those two equations hold:

$h:c\rightarrow b^a$

commuting morphisms:

$eval: b_a\times a\rightarrow b$
$f:c\times a\rightarrow b$
$h\times id: c\times a\rightarrow b^a\times a$